# proving that the quotient linear map of a continuous linear map is also continuous (normed spaces)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be a normed vector spaces over $\mathbb K $, $T:X\to Y$ a $\mathbb K$-linear continuous map ($\mathbb K$ could be $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$).

Let's consider $ \hat T: X/\ker T \to Y$ the induced linear map ( $\hat T (\bar x)=T(x)$. This map it's well defined and it's clearly injective. We consider the usual quotient norm.
I want to prove that $\hat T$ it's also continuous and also $\|\hat T\|=\|T\|$.

I only proved that $\|T\|\le \|\hat T\|$ if I prove the other inequality, then I'm done with the continuity but I don't know how.

Comment: Try to show that the projection $\pi \colon X \to X/\ker T$ maps the open unit ball of $X$ onto the open unit ball of $X/\ker T$.

Comment: That is equivalent to prove $||\hat T||=||T||$ I don't know how

Comment: Right, it's equivalent. But methinks easier to handle, since you know exactly what the quotient map does. How to prove it: recall first what the definition of the norm on $X/N$ is.

Comment: That's the difficult part, prove that if $||x||\le 1$ then $||\pi (x)||=||\bar x|| \le 1$

Comment: That one is the easy part, that part is even true for the closed unit ball. What was the definition of the norm on the quotient again?

Comment: Look, I proved that the map is continuous because $T = \hat T o \pi $ and $\pi$ is an open map. My problem is the following, when I'm trying to prove that $ ||\hat T||\le ||T||$ I know that is enough to consider some $ \bar x$ such that $ ||\bar x|| = 1 $ my problem is that it's not necessary that $||x||\le 1$ and that's my problem :/

Comment: Don't care about $\lVert \bar{x}\rVert = 1$. That leads to frustration. Care only about $\lVert x\rVert < 1$ and $\lVert \bar{x}\rVert < 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer You are right, thanks dude :D!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything follows easily from the

**Lemma:** Let $X$ a normed space, $N \subset X$ a closed subspace, and $\pi \colon X \to X/N$ the canonical projection. Let $U = \{ x \in X : \lVert x\rVert < 1\}$ and $U_N = \{ y \in X/N : \lVert y\rVert < 1\}$ the open unit balls in $X$ resp. $X/N$. Then $\pi(U) = U_N$.

Assuming the lemma, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lVert \hat{T}\rVert &= \sup \{ \lVert \hat{T}(\xi)\rVert : \xi \in U_N\}\\
&= \sup \{\lVert \hat{T}(\xi)\rVert : \xi \in \pi(U)\}\\
&= \sup \{\lVert \hat{T}(\pi(x))\rVert : x \in U\}\\
&= \sup \{ \lVert T(x)\rVert : x \in U\}\\
&= \lVert T\rVert.
\end{align}$$

To prove the lemma, recall that the norm on the quotient space is given by

$$\lVert \pi(x)\rVert := \inf \{ \lVert x+n\rVert : n \in N\}.$$

Thus, since $0 \in N$, we trivially have $\lVert \pi(x)\rVert \leqslant \lVert x\rVert$, whence $\pi(U) \subset U_N$.

Conversely, if $\xi = \pi(x) \in U_N$, let $\nu := \lVert \xi\rVert$. By the definition of the quotient norm, there is an $n_x \in N$ with $\lVert x+n_x\rVert < \frac{1+\nu}{2} < 1$. But $\xi = \pi(x) = \pi(x+n_x)$, and $x+n_x \in U$, so $\xi \in \pi(U)$.

Comment: Why can't we just argue that $\pi: X \to X/K$ is continuous and linear and therefore so is $T \circ \pi$?

Comment: We don't have $T\circ \pi$ here, we have $T = \hat{T}\circ \pi$. We know that $\pi$ and $\hat{T} \circ \pi$ are continuous, but that alone does not imply that $\hat{T}$ is continuous, we need some special properties of $\pi$ to conclude that.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. But how does $0 \in N$ imply that $\|\pi(x)\|\le \|x\|$?

Comment: Oh I see. Never mind my previous comment. It's the definition of the norm on the quotient.

Comment: But why does there exists $n_x$ with $\|x + n_x\| < {1+\nu \over 2}<1$?

Comment: By definition of the quotient norm we only get an $n_x$ with $$\|x+n_x\|\le \nu + \varepsilon$$
Right? Did you mean to write $$ \|x + n_x\| \le {1\over 2}+\nu$$
perhaps?

Comment: Perhaps one could argue like this: Note that $\nu < 1$ and let $\delta := {|1-\nu| \over 4}$. By definition of the quotient norm there exists an $n_x$ such that 
$$ \|x + n_x\|< \nu + \delta < 1$$

Comment: @student Pick $\varepsilon = \frac{1-\nu}{2}$, then $\nu + \varepsilon = \frac{1+\nu}{2}$. It's the argument of your last comment, but with a different $\delta$.